# Windows Github issue pushing a new folder

Tags: github, synchronization, directory, addition, visual-sourcesafe

I'm a VSS (Visual source safe) & Dropbox guy but new to GitHub. I'm using [Windows Github tool](http://windows.github.com/) to manage repositories on our remote server as I concluded in my previous [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722989/small-team-remote-server-based-simple-version-control-vcs). I was glad to have sought this single point easy to use tool without any need for a deeper knowledge of git.

> Things have been working fine until one day I had to add a new folder
>   to my repository. The Windows Github tool wouldn't recognize the
>   folder as a new content to be pushed! After some struggle I derived
>   that it "**does**" maintain sync with my "**initial folders**" but simply
>   **creating a new folder in the repository directory wouldn't sync it**
>   like Dropbox!

I searched to know how I can do it or if I had to use GitShell. My bad any I tried it, failed. Finally, I decided to purge everything and re-create the repository folder structure with this new folder like I did with my initial setup. But I don't know how or why it kept saying that **the /.git/index file was being used by another process**. I tried to empty this folder but it wouldn't. Finally, a logoff was able to free that file for me and I re-created everything. Pheew!

I might be doing it wrong as a newbie or even misusing Git due to my Dropbox habits. Pls correct me! What would be the best way?

My usage is more like VSS & dropbox(with version control) in a small remotely connected team. I started with this simple [Windows Github tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx). What about the following two -

- [TortoiseGit](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/165)
- [msysgit](http://robertgreiner.com/2010/02/getting-started-with-git-and-tortoisegit-on-windows/)

Do they provide better management? Pls suggest if Windows GitHub is the best (if so how to add folders later?)

Comment: Did you try to `git add` the new elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case, do note that adding a folder won't trigger anything for Git: you won't be able to push it if that folder is empty, because Git will consider it as "no content", and will ignore that new folder.

See also "[How do I add an empty directory to a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)".

If you add a folder *and some files in it*, then the GitHub for Windows interface will detect that new content, and ask you to add and commit, which means you will be able to push.

Comment: Actually that is what I expected Windows Github tool to do - I added a new folder with a new zip file but still it wouldn't detect it as a new push change - any reasons?

Comment: @HemantTank strange, unless you have a .gitignore file set to ignore .zip file (which is possible if your repo is created with GitHub for Windows, as that tool might set it up directly with a .gitignore file). Don't forget Git is ill-suited for binary management, so archives (zip, tgz, ...) are usually stored elsewhere, not in a DVCS.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Well, this new setup seem to be doing that! What might have caused the old one to misbehave? I mean this was a simple operation! Also can you provide some more info on how to manage the gitignore file and is there a way to push updates automatically (i.e. like dropbox). Thank you.